# How to update asset using eam web service toolkit

Tags: asp.net, infor-eam

I am new to the eam/web services toolkit.  I am trying to update an asset.  However, I am not finding a wsdl in the toolkit to update an asset.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Resolved.  The concept of "Update" does not exist.  The correct wsdl for update is "sync":

MP0303_SyncAssetEquipment_001.wsdl

And you must pass all fields.  Here is a quick way to know what you need to pass:

- Run infor xml generator
- Open xsd (From your infor schemas folder, MP*.xsd)
- Setup header/body (with your user/pass/param values, etc)
- Save that as an xml file
- Open infor web sevices test utility
- Open xml created above/point to service url

These steps will help you test and setup your wsdl with the correct params and test it to see if it works.

Comment: Are you still using the EAM Web Service? Do you have some sample code to use it with C#?